# ngClick doesn't fire controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these two buttons

```
<div ng-controller='ArticleController as article'>
    <button type='button' ng-click='article.show()'>Remove</button>
    ...
    <div class="modal modal-fade">
        ...
        <button type='button' ng-click='article.remove()'>Ok</button>
```

and my controller

```
foo = ->
    console.log 'foo'
    return

angular.module 'myModule', []
.controller 'ArticleController',  ['jQuery', ($) ->
    @bar = 'bar'
    @show = ->
        $('.modal').modal()
        return
    @remove = ->
        foo()
        return
    return
]
```

the first button is firing the function, the second is not.

I've tried to change the `ng-click` directive to a scoped function, and the controller like this

```
angular.module 'myModule', []
.controller 'ArticleController', ['jQuery', '$scope', ($, $scope) ->
    @bar = 'bar'
    @show = ->
        $('.modal').modal()
        return
    $scope.remove = ->
        foo()
        return
    return
]
```

but nothing changed. I don't get why it can't fire that function.

Comment: Did you look at it in source of browser or debugger?

Comment: did you check the debugger?

Comment: are you asking if I put a breakpoint in the `remove` function?

Comment: @fra9001, yes. You must look at its.

Comment: What does foo() do? Where is it defined?

Comment: What is the foo function? add there another function and try again please. for example alert("huba");